# Uncaught TypeError: Waypoint.Infinite is not a constructor at infinite_scroll.js:1:16

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I am trying to use Jquery waypoints and infinite scroll on a Django app, but I keep getting this error for some reason. Can anyone tell me why? I already tried the answers from [Waypoint.Infinite is not a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64757280/waypoint-infinite-is-not-a-constructor) but they don't help me. Any suggestions?

**infinite_scroll.js**

```
var infinite = new Waypoint.Infinite({
    element: $('.infinite-container')[0],

    offset: 'bottom-in-view',

    onBeforePageLoad: function () {
        
    },
    onAfterPageLoad: function () {
      
    }

});
```